# How to use return value of a Bash command such as "ifconfig" to be used as an argument for an if statement in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, python, bash-scripting

I'm relatively new to Bash scripting but I'm very familiar with Python and many Bash commands. I was wondering if it's possible to use a command such as `ifconfig eno1` and use the output as a condition to be used in an `if` statement. Basically, if you issue:

```
 ifconfig eno1
```

and you get an active IP, is there any way to save the output of that to a variable as a 1/0 or true/false, to be used in the following `if` statement example (assuming `ifoutput` is the variable name):

```
 if [ "$ifoutput" == "$True"]

 then 
         echo connection is active! 
 fi
```

I thought of possibly calling a Python script that does essentially the same thing, however I was thinking I would run into the same issue; being no way to get an individual return value from the Python script to be used in the `if` statement. Please advise and please go easy on me -- as I said I am relatively new to Bash scripting! I already have methods of doing this strictly using Python, however I am trying to learn more about Bash scripting. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could write it to file using `> filename.txt` or pipe it to a different command, `| nextCommand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifconfig` will return a numeric 8-bit value when it completes (like any *nix process that exits cleanly).

Typically zero (`0`) is used to indicate success, and another value is used to indicate failure. This return code is available as `$?`.

`ifconfig` will also output to `stdout`, for example:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:14:00:02
          inet addr:172.20.0.2  Bcast:172.20.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20430143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20966475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:46532669457 (46.5 GB)  TX bytes:44114090048 (44.1 GB)
```

If you are trying to determine if `ifconfig eth0` was successful (i.e: permissions depending, the interface exists), then you could do one of the following:

```bsh
ifconfig eth0
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo yay
fi
```

```bsh
if ifconfig eth0; then
  echo yay
fi
```

```bsh
ifconfig eth0 && echo yay
```

Hiding `ifconfig`'s output can be achieved by appending a `> /dev/null`:

```bsh
if ifconfig eth0 > /dev/null; then
  echo yay
fi
```

---

You asked about printing the return code, and this is a gotcha for beginners...

You can simply do this:

```
ifconfig eth0
echo $?
```

But after calling on `echo`, the return code (`$?`) will be `echo`'s return code, not `ifconfig`'s... To deal with that, just assign it to a temporary variable:

```
ifconfig eth0
RET=$?
echo ${RET}
if [ ${RET} -eq 0 ]; then
  echo yay
fi
```

---

Note: `[` is a built-in command that can evaluate expressions, the square braces (`[` / `]`) are not actually part of the `if` syntax:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

---

If you are actually trying to *get the IP address of an interface*, then you might want to use a pipeline, like one of the following (there are many ways to achieve the same result):

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eom1 'inet addr:([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | cut -d: -f2
ifconfig eth0 | sed -re '/inet addr:/!d;s/^[^:]+://;s/ .*$//'
```

Comment: Thank you! Initially I had thought of using the exit code, but since I am still fairly new , I didn't realize the exit codes would be similar to what i'm used to working with in Python! Thanks for the additional information as well! I feel confident I can carry out my project now! is there any way to show the exit code upon execution?

Comment: No problem - and of course! `echo $?`... see my edit for explanation of a gotcha though.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html -> Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide - has a lot of information regarding Bash and scripting.